# How do I disable a certain monitor, and enable it back only when it is on ?

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

I have 3 monitors connecting to the PC. I have them set up like this.

[image]

The third monitor (TV) keep showing/detecting in my PC even if it is not even **ON**, and make my windows goes up there. It's a bit a annoying.

Well, you might say, just unhook the HDMI cable for that monitor, but I don't want to do that manually each time. I'm **wondering** if we can do it via Windows or some third party application.

How do I disable a certain monitor, and enable it back only when it is on ?